# Path setting for DLL's in JBOSS 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We have some DLL's which are related to `Java,VB`. In `Joss 4.X` , We used to place in bin directory under Application Server.

We migrated to `JBOSS 7.1.1` and when I removed from bin directory and placed them in libraries folder  under `C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\correction\main\libraries` .

I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xxxJavaWrapper in java.library.path
java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xxxJavaWrapperJNI.new_xxx()J
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.correction">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="xxx.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="xyz.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="libraries"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="libraries"/>
                </paths>
                <exports>
                    <include-set>
                        <path name="libraries"/>
                    </include-set>
                </exports>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
```

But I place the same dll's in bin folder, it is working fine.
   I want to place them in module folder and set the path from there instead of bin so that I can have all the application related jar's, properties and dll files at one place for ease maintainance.

Also I want to know how to set the path of txt and properties files in jboss 7.1.1

Regards
Srini

Answer (score 5):

Configure **module.xml** as below:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.correction">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="xxx.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xyz.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="lib/win-x86_64"/>
    </resources>

   <dependencies>
       <module name="sun.jdk"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Put the DLLs into the directory **lib/win-x86_64**. Check the another dependencies of your project.

In **WEB-INF** of your application creating the file **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** and put the content below:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
     <dependencies>
        <module name="com.correction"/>
     </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

That's all.

Another Question: How can you make these properties files accessible to applications deployed on JBoss 7?

create a custom module where you put your properties files and put **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** to your application archive **(WAR/EAR)** to use that custom module.

Create the new module directory under **$JBOSS_HOME/modules**(using app/conf in this example)

```
mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME/modules/app/conf/main/properties/
```

Put your properties files in **$JBOSS_HOME/modules/app/conf/main/properties/**

Create a module.xmlhere **$JBOSS_HOME/modules/app/conf/main/module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="app.conf">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="properties"/>
   </resources>
</module>
```

put the following **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** in **WEB-INF**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
            <module name="app.conf" />
   </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then you can access your properties files using thecode below (example assumes you have a
example.propertiesfile in **$JBOSS_HOME/modules/app/conf/main/properties/**)

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("example.properties");
```

Ps: I used JBoss AS 7.1.2 ( JBoss EAP 6 )

Regards
Mauricio Magnani