# JBoss 7 is trying to load modules libraries from JBoss bin

Tags: linux, module, jboss7.x

I got a module, described like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mymodule">  
  <resources> 
    <resource-root path="myFirstJar.jar" />
    <resource-root path="mySecondJar.jar" />
    <resource-root path="Lib/linux" />
  </resources>
</module>
```

In my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure><deployment>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="com.mymodule" />
  </dependencies>
</deployment></jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The jar files are found, but one of them tries to access an .so library. That library exist in the "Lib/linux" folder. But JBoss will look into %JBOSS_HOME%/bin/mylib.so .
I tried to follow the naming convention (see [jboss.org](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Native+Libraries)), getting the same error:

*Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/local/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/mylib.so*

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
If I put the .so file into my JBoss/bin folder, then the JVM crash on a JNI call.

Comment: Brother, i read in your comments below on my answer that you solved it somehow.. if that is so, can you answer your own question? will be helpful for others landing here. 
thanks

Comment: Good remark. 
The libraries I am after are installed with a program. I ended writing my module with relative path to the JARs, finding them directly in the program lib folder. For the libraries, I don't have to refer to them. They are loaded in the system because the program is running as a service on the machine. The errors I got were more about a problem with that program than a problem with JBoss.

Comment: it would be better if you can put that description in the `Answer your own question ` at the bottom of page in case none of the answers is/are relevant. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this should solve your problem.

in your `module.xml` of module `com.mymodule`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mymodule">  
  <resources> 
    <resource-root path="myFirstJar.jar" />
    <resource-root path="mySecondJar.jar" />
    <resource-root path="Lib/linux" />
  </resources>
 <dependencies>
 <module name="javax.api"/>
 <module name="THE JAR IT IS TRYING TO LOOK OUTSIDE"/>
 </dependencies>

</module>
```

you need to add dependency of your module on the jar it is dependent on to have it work

Comment: Thanks for your help Mukul. It's not a jar I'm looking for, but a library. And if I put a direct reference to it in my `module.xml`, then JBoss will tell me it cannot read that strange jar.
Anyhow, I succeed to find the library by setting my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the folder containing the library.

Comment: @SylvainSchüpp , brother , can you elaborate on "library" I dint quite follow. what exactly? what format ? is it like a collection of jars ?

Comment: With library, I mean .so file on Linux, or .dll file on Windows. Also C/C++ archive.

Comment: in that case check out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775827/path-setting-for-dlls-in-jboss-7-1-1,

Answer (score 0):

The libraries I am after are installed with a program. I ended writing my module with relative path to the JARs, finding them directly in the program lib folder. For the libraries, I don't have to refer to them. They are loaded in the system because the program is running as a service on the machine. The errors I got were more about a problem with that program than a problem with JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming Lib/linux to lib/linux-i686/  and/or lib/linux-x86_64/. We seem to use this in our shipped module setup for the org.hornetq  and org.jboss.as.web modules