# OpenCV as JBoss-as global module

Tags: java, opencv, jboss, java-native-interface

## Problem presentation

I try to install OpenCV as global module of a JBoss-as instance. The versions are:

- JBoss-as: 7.1.1 Final
- OpenCV: 2.4.5 (compiled with Java support)

I started from a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04 64 bits with only JBoss-as and OpenCV installed.

## Preamble

The OpenCV java wrapper use JNI calls. Thus two things are required:

- opencv-245.jar
- libopencv_java245.so

And available in `/usr/share/OpenCV/java/` (regarding to installation)

I also point some observations:

1. The installation of JBoss is correct (applications can be deployed and are working)
2. The compilation and installation of OpenCV with java support is correct (Java class using OpenCV are working)
3. A basic web application using OpenCV and deployed, with maven, on JBoss-as works (the `opencv-245.jar` is listed as dependency in `pom.xml`, and thus packaged into the `war`)

## Problem description

As soon as I define OpenCV as JBoss global module (setting `<scope>provided</scope>` in pom.xml) this exception is raised:

```java
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:441)
    WS.printMessage(WS.java:15)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

It appears that the OpenCV `jar` library is found because the exception is raised from it. Also it does not complains about some library not found like (taken from first link at the end):

```java
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xxxx in java.library.path
```

thus I guess the `libopencv_java245.so` is not the problem. The precise configuration is described below.

## Configurations

I defined the `org.opencv` module in `modules/org/opencv/main/module.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.opencv">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="opencv-245.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Then I put in the same folder `opencv-245.jar` and also `libopencv_java245.so` in `lib/linux-x86_64/` subfolder (as explained in [Native Library](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Native+Libraries))

To define this module as global I modified in `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
    <global-modules>
        <module name="org.opencv" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
</subsystem>
```

Finally to use the global module I set in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.opencv" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I also reminds that I have put `<scope>provided</scope>` in my maven `pom.xml`.

Also, putting:

```java
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245");
```

or not in the code doesn't change anything.

## Extra observations

I also noticed that with an `ear` application, composed of one `war` and one `jar`, even the procedure described in point 3 in "Preamble" does not work and give the same exception as above. Maybe this information can help.

Someone have some pointers or solutions?

## Related questions

- [Path setting for DLL's in JBOSS 7.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775827/path-setting-for-dlls-in-jboss-7-1-1)
- [JBoss 7 is trying to load modules libraries from JBoss bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896950/jboss-7-is-trying-to-load-modules-libraries-from-jboss-bin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solve the problem and write here the answer to help other people.

The problem wasn't in the path of the `libopencv_java245.so`, but in the JBoss Classloaders.

For the case decribed in Preamble point 3 (which worked), the ClassLoader that load the `war` file is the same that load `opencv-245.jar` (which is embedded into the `war`), and the call to `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245")` in my code has effect on this same ClassLoader, because it has loaded the Class containing this method call. All has effect on the same ClassLoader and everything work.

Now the reason why it is not working with an `ear` follow up from the fact that an `ear` has its own ClassLoader, and then each subdeployment as another one. The first ClassLoader deploy the `ear`, which contains the `opencv-245.jar` dependecy, then another ClassLoader deploy the `war` contained into the `ear`. Because the call `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245")` is in the `war`, the effect of this command has effect on the ClassLoader of the `war`, but the `opencv-245.jar` is loaded into the `ear` ClassLoader. Thus when trying to call native library, java can't find the link because they are on different ClassLoader.

Finally the point of interest here is for a JBoss module. When describing a module as configured in my initial question, this is a high level JBoss ClassLoader which load the `opencv-245.jar`. The ClassLoader will also automatically know where to search for native libraries: in `$MODULE_PATH/lib/linux-x86_64/`. But the problem is to load the library. The call to `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245")` must be done in the same ClassLoader that have charged `opencv-245.jar`. Thus it is not possible to load library like this in your code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245");
}
```

because it will has effect on the ClassLoader that have load your Class, not on the JBoss one. The solution is to modify the `opencv-245.jar` and add into it a `org.opencv.core.Loader` class for instance, which have only one method:

```
package org.opencv.core

class Loader
{
    public static void loadLibrary(String name)
    {
        System.loadLibrary(name);
    }
}
```

Then in your class you can put:

```
static {
    Loader.loadLibrary("opencv_java245");
}
```

And the `System.loadLibrary` call being placed in `opencv-245.jar` will have effect one the same ClassLoader that load the `opencv-245.jar`. Then native call are correctly linked because both library, the `jar` and the `so`, were loaded in the same ClassLoader.

Comment: An improvement to your answer, now in OpenCV 3 there is a class used for osgi but work for our purposes. So instead of injecting the class, just call  `new org.opencv.osgi.OpenCVNativeLoader().init();`

Comment: @carlos-rafael-ramirez I don't use OpenCV nor Java any longer. I transformed this answer to a community wiki, feel free to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenCV (org.openpnp package) 3.4.2+ instead of:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

you can use:

```
OpenCV.loadLocally();
```

I'm using jboss wildfly, and had problem when doing more than one deploy. Native classes were already loaded, but this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the libopencv_java245.so file to the same directory you created for your OpenCV module. then add it as a resource so it will be added to the classpath and be available at runtime.

So your module.xml will look like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.opencv">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="opencv-245.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: That throw an Exception: `Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /opt/jboss-as/modules/org/opencv/main/module.xml
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,53]
Message: Failed to add resource root 'libopencv_java245.so' at path 'libopencv_java245.so'`

Comment: I edited the module.xml file to include the path of the current directory of the jar file. Be sure the .so file is in the same directory and I'm thinking it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I also found a forum posting that might help https://community.jboss.org/thread/206389